# read input from user in while loop having input and output redirection

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

This is my code:

```
while IFS=',' read a b c; do
     read input
     echo $input
done 3<&0 < input.csv > output.txt
```

I took care of input redirection by redirecting through pipeline. But still,when I run the above code, control does not stop for input.

Why?

Answer (score 4):

It's because your input stream is feeding both `read`. You're almost right, so maybe it's a typo (you just forgot to give to right FD to your second `read`) :

```
while IFS=',' read a b c; do
  read input <&3
  echo $input
done 3<&0 < input.csv >> output.txt
```

Comment: yeah I missed that, thanks again. I can read input from while loop now, however when I try the same inside a function called in while loop, it does not work.

Comment: @Menon Why? You just have to replace your `read input <&3` by `my_function <&3` and it should work.